# Compiling dependencies in node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm

So. I have been trying to use this project i cloned from GitHub.
when I try to compile better-sqlite3@7.1.2
here is the logs:

```
[canvas] Success: "C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node" is installed via remote

> better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3
> prebuild-install || npm run build-release

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.15.4 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

> better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3
> node-gyp rebuild --release


C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
  extract_sqlite3
  sqlite3.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\stdarg.h(1,1): warning
C4821: Unable to determine Unicode encoding type, please save the file with signature (BOM) [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\Dracon
ianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\sqlite3\sqlite3.c(
3857,56): error C2081: 'va_list': name in formal parameter list illegal [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_module
s\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\sqlite3\sqlite3.c(
3859,67): error C2081: 'va_list': name in formal parameter list illegal [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_module
s\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\sqlite3\sqlite3.c(
8963,81): error C2081: 'va_list': name in formal parameter list illegal [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_module
s\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\intrin.h(1,1): warning
C4821: Unable to determine Unicode encoding type, please save the file with signature (BOM) [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\Dracon
ianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\vcruntime.h(1,1): warni
ng C4821: Unable to determine Unicode encoding type, please save the file with signature (BOM) [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\Dra
conianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(156,19): error C2054: expected '(' to follow
 '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(156,29): error C2085: '__crt_bool': not in f
ormal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(278,58): error C2085: '_invalid_parameter_no
info': not in formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.
vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(279,84): error C2085: '_invalid_parameter_no
info_noreturn': not in formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps
\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(283,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing
')' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxp
roj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(283,16): error C2085: '_invoke_watson': not
in formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(283,16): error C2146: syntax error: missing
',' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxp
roj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(283,24): error C2143: syntax error: missing
';' before 'const' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(287,35): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [C:\
Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(520,5): error C2061: syntax error: identifie
r '_Field_range_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(522,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [C:\U
sers\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(12,1): error C2061: syntax erro
r: identifier '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.
vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(12,1): error C2059: syntax erro
r: ';' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(83,20): error C2061: syntax err
or: identifier '_Ret_notnull_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxpr
oj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(83,20): error C2059: syntax err
or: ';' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(85,63): error C2061: syntax err
or: identifier '__local_stdio_printf_options' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\dep
s\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(85,63): error C2059: syntax err
or: ';' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(85,96): error C2059: syntax err
or: '<parameter-list>' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(93,20): error C2061: syntax err
or: identifier '_Ret_notnull_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxpr
oj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(93,20): error C2059: syntax err
or: ';' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(95,63): error C2061: syntax err
or: identifier '__local_stdio_scanf_options' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps
\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(95,63): error C2059: syntax err
or: ';' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h(95,95): error C2059: syntax err
or: '<parameter-list>' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(15,1): error C2061: syntax error: ide
ntifier '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxpro
j]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(15,1): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
 [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(49,17): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ')' before identifier 'FILE' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.v
cxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(50,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
 [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(50,10): error C2085: '_Stream': not i
n formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(53,45): error C2085: '_fgetwchar': no
t in formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(57,17): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ')' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite
3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(57,17): error C2085: 'fputwc': not in
 formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(57,17): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ',' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite
3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(57,25): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ',' before identifier '_Character' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sql
ite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(58,17): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ',' before identifier 'FILE' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.v
cxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(58,21): error C2143: syntax error: mi
ssing ';' before '*' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(58,32): error C2059: syntax error: ')
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(62,14): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ')' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite
3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(62,14): error C2061: syntax error: id
entifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(62,14): error C2059: syntax error: ';
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(63,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
 [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(66,21): error C2054: expected '(' to
follow '_Check_return_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(67,17): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ')' before identifier 'FILE' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.v
cxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(67,17): error C2085: 'getwc': not in
formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(67,17): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ',' before identifier 'FILE' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.v
cxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(67,21): error C2143: syntax error: mi
ssing ';' before '*' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(68,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
 [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(71,21): error C2054: expected '(' to
follow '_Check_return_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(71,43): error C2085: 'getwchar': not
in formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(75,5): error C2061: syntax error: ide
ntifier '_Success_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(84,17): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ')' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite
3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(84,17): error C2061: syntax error: id
entifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(84,17): error C2059: syntax error: ';
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(85,17): error C2146: syntax error: mi
ssing ';' before identifier 'FILE' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.v
cxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(85,21): error C2143: syntax error: mi
ssing '{' before '*' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(86,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
 [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(89,15): error C2143: syntax error: mi
ssing ')' before 'return' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(89,15): error C2143: syntax error: mi
ssing '{' before 'return' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(89,15): error C2059: syntax error: 'r
eturn' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(89,26): error C2059: syntax error: ')
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(103,17): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ')' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlit
e3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(103,17): error C2061: syntax error: i
dentifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(103,17): error C2059: syntax error: '
;' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(104,9): error C2373: '_Inout_': redef
inition; different type modifiers [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vc
xproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(85): message : see declaration of '_I
nout_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(104,17): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ';' before identifier 'FILE' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.
vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(104,21): error C2143: syntax error: m
issing '{' before '*' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(105,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(109,14): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ')' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlit
e3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(109,14): error C2061: syntax error: i
dentifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(109,14): error C2059: syntax error: '
;' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(110,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(114,16): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ')' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlit
e3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(114,16): error C2061: syntax error: i
dentifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(114,16): error C2059: syntax error: '
;' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(115,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(119,17): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ')' before identifier 'wint_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite
3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(119,34): error C2082: redefinition of
 formal parameter '_Character' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxpr
oj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(120,17): error C2082: redefinition of
 formal parameter '_Inout_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(120,17): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ',' before identifier 'FILE' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.
vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(120,21): error C2143: syntax error: m
issing ';' before '*' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(121,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(123,5): error C2086: 'int _Check_retu
rn_': redefinition [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(70): message : see declaration of '_C
heck_return_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(124,19): error C2054: expected '(' to
 follow '_Check_return_' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(125,31): error C2143: syntax error: m
issing ')' before 'type' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(125,31): error C2085: '_wfdopen': not
 in formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(125,31): error C2143: syntax error: m
issing ';' before 'type' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(125,42): error C2085: '_FileHandle':
not in formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj
]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(126,16): error C2085: '_In_z_': not i
n formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(126,16): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ',' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlit
e3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(126,24): error C2143: syntax error: m
issing ';' before 'const' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(127,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(129,20): error C2061: syntax error: i
dentifier '_CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.
vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(129,20): error C2059: syntax error: '
;' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(130,18): error C2054: expected '(' to
 follow '_wfopen_s' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(131,16): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ')' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlit
e3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(131,16): error C2085: '_wfopen': not
in formal parameter list [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(131,16): error C2146: syntax error: m
issing ',' before identifier 'wchar_t' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlit
e3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(131,24): error C2143: syntax error: m
issing ';' before 'const' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(133,9): error C2059: syntax error: ')
' [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(133,9): fatal error C1003: error coun
t exceeds 100; stopping compilation [C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\sqlite3.
vcxproj]
←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mbuild error←[0m
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mstack←[0m Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mstack←[0m     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mstack←[0m     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mstack←[0m     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mSystem←[0m Windows_NT 10.0.19042
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mcommand←[0m "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mcwd←[0m C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\DraconianJSBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mnode -v←[0m v14.15.4
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mnode-gyp -v←[0m v5.1.0
←[0m←[37;40mgyp←[0m ←[0m←[31;40mERR!←[0m ←[0m←[35mnot ok←[0m
←[0mnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release: `node-gyp rebuild --release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CJ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-03T01_05_32_029Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install: `prebuild-install || npm run build-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CJ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-03T01_05_32_700Z-debug.log
```

I tried* everything to try and make it work.

- clearing npm`s cache
- deleting node_modules

---

but all other projects on my computer work just fine.
Can you guys on the internet help?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a native module. If it's not providing prebuilt binary, then you will need to compile from source.

It's using node-gyp to build. In order for that to work, you need to install all node-gyp requirements => See here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-unix